# Rails rendering after sort

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I am a beginner to rails.  In one of my index views I have been struggling to get my form to render the first result of an array after I sorted it.  I get the following error message:

> Couldn't find Answer without an ID

When I look at all the elements in the array I see the Answer ID for each.  Just not sure why my render is not picking in up.  My code from my index view is below.

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
  <p><%= link_to question.title, question_path(question.id) %></p>      
    <!-- Answer Sorted with Most Votes - Start -->
      <% ans = question.answers.sort {|a, b| b.points <=> a.points} %>
      <%= render 'answers/form', answer: Answer.find(ans.first)%>
    <!-- Answer Sorted with Most Votes - End -->
<% end %>
```

Note - When I change my render to the following everything renders fine:

```
<%= render 'answers/form', answer: Answer.first%>
```

My error comes when I try get it to render the first result of my sort.  Any help is very much appreciated.  This one has me totally stumped.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: The subsequent `Answer.find` is redundant. Just render `ans.first`.

Comment: A suggest to improve your code: You could sort your answers by the db. It seems you wanna have a descending order: `first_answer = question.answers.order("points DESC").limit(1).first` and `render 'answers/form', answer: first_answer`

Comment: Thanks for both the suggestions above, I have added both to my program.  I do really appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement will return an array:

```
<% ans = question.answers.sort {|a, b| b.points <=> a.points} %>
```

If you want the first record after sorting you can do something like:

```
<% ans = question.answers.sort{|a, b| b.points <=> a.points}.first %>
<%= render 'answers/form', answer: ans %>
```

and it should resolve the issue by returning the first `Answer` record from the expression.

Comment: Thanks.  This helped.  It resulted in a "no routes match" error.  Looking at this more closely I realized some of my questions did not have answers so I was trying to render a nil answer on some questions.  I surrounded the render with ```<% if ans %>``` and it now works great.  Thanks again.